# Setup Babel + Uglify + Karma using Grunt

Tags: karma-jasmine, babeljs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I´m trying to setup a build workflow using the aforementioned technologies, but I´m getting the following error, which seems very generic upon running tests on karma:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.Sifter=b()')
```

This happens even without adding any ECMSA6 specific feature. The same workflow works fine without the transpiling phase in the workflow.

What I tried was to set the babeljs after a concatenation phase and before executing a uglifying on it, like the following snippet:

```
  var defaultTasks = [
        "sass:prod", // compile scss sources
        "cleanAll", // clean folders: preparing for copy
        "copyAll", // copying bower files
        "cssmin:customVendor", // minify and concat 'customized from vendor' css
        "concat:vendorStyles", // concat vendors's css + minified 'customized from vendor' and distribute as 'css/vendor.css'
        "uglify:rawVendors", // minifies unminified vendors
        "concat:vendorScripts", // concat vendors's scripts and distribute as 'scripts/vendor.js'
        "ngAnnotate:app", // ng-annotates app's scripts
        "concat:appScripts", // concat app's (customized from vendor's + ng-annotated + customer's)
        "babel",// uses babeljs to convert brandnew ES6 javascript into ES5 allowing for old browsers
        "uglify:app" // minify app script and distribute as 'scripts/app.js'
    ];
    if (!skipTest) {
        defaultTasks.push("karma:target");  // run tests on minified scripts
    }
```

The imporant definitions are shown:

```
   babel: {
            options: {
                "presets": ['es2015']
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    "<%= concat.appScripts.dest %>": "<%= concat.appScripts.dest %>"
                }
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: {
                    except: [
                        "jQuery", "angular", "tableau", "LZString", "moment", "Moment", "Modernizr",
                        "app", "modules"
                    ]
                }
            },
            app: {
                files: [{
                    src: ["<%= concat.appScripts.dest %>"],
                    dest: "<%= app.dist %>/scripts/app.js"
                }]
            }
        },
```

I´ve tested the transpile a bit, running the default logic from babel url, and it works well, converting basic stuff.

Is there any better workflow that I could use to still run the tests against the same code that would be executed for real?

Thanks

Comment: Found that the mentioned error refers to Selectize.js, but I still don´t know how it is related to the build.

The selectize, however is included on the concatenated file. Will keep digging

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the workflow was correct.

I just need to modify the filesets a bit in order to avoid transpiling the selectize.js file (which wasn´t really needed).

However, not sure why it was breaking

That solved to me, so I´m closing the question, but perhaps might be useful for someone else.